# How do I fix "cannot resolve method"?

Tags: java, class, methods

So first I have this class:

```
public float getPixel(int height, int width)
{
   return data[height][width];
}

public void setPixel(float value, int height, int width)
{
   if (value > getMax())
     value = getMax();
   if (value < 0)
    value = 0;
   data[height][width] = value;
}

private Image(String magicNumber, int height, int width, float max) {
  this.magicNumber = magicNumber;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.max = max;
  data = new float[height][width];
}
...
public Image clone()
{
  Image clone = new Image(getMagicNumber(), getHeight(), getWidth(), getMax());
   for (int i = 0; i < getHeight(); i++)
   {
     for (int j = 0; j < getWidth(); j++)
     {
        clone.setPixel(getPixel(i, j), i, j);
     }
   }
  return clone;
}
```

And then this class:

```
public class Filter {

    public Filter() {

    }

    public Image linearFilter(Image image, float[][] kernel)
    {
        Image filtered = image.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < getHeight(); i++) 
        {  /* cannot resolve getHeight*/
            ...
        }
         return filtered;
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1) Why do I don't need to create an instance of the class Image. Here I can already use filtered.setPixels...

2) How do I fix the Problem with "cannot resolve method"?

Comment: Don't call methods that don't exist. Perhaps you mean to call `image.getHeight(...)`? Hard to tell since we don't know what this code is supposed to do. Is Image a `java.awt.Image`?

Comment: (1) You _do_ create an instance of `Image`.  What do you think `image.clone()` does?  (2) When you call a method, you have to specify which object you're calling it on.  Here, you probably want to follow Mr Hovercraft's advice and write `image.getHeight()`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, a clarification: if it is the `java.awt.Image` interface though there is no `getHeight()` method. Instead he'd have to use the `getHeight​(ImageObserver observer)` method.

Comment: Ooh right. Thanks @Hovercraft. Looks like I misrepresented you slightly.

Comment: All the methods that you see in the snipped exist. And the first snipped (class) is called `Image`. If I want to create an instance of `Image`, don't I have to do `Image filtered = new Image ()` to get access to the methods of `Image`? I don't understand what  `Image filtered = image.clone()` is doing? How is this creating an instace?

Comment: still need help with the my question above  in the comment... :(

Answer (score -1):

I can't really tell from your post because the first snippet you've posted doesn't seem to be an entire class but rather a portion of it. I assume you have an Image class, and that Image class has a method called `getHeight()`.

Inside the for loop condition `for (int i = 0; i < getHeight(); i++)`, you'll most likely want to change `getHeight()` to `filtered.getHeight()` because `getHeight()` is a method inside of the `Image` class, and `filtered` is (presumably) of type `Image`.

Comment: Yes, I have an `Image` class and that class has the `getHeight()` method (that was the first snippet). I don' t quite understand how we are creating an instance in the class `Filter` inside the `linearFilter` method. In other words: what is `Image filtered = image.clone()` doing? How is this creating an instance? I am used to do `Image filtered = new Image ()` for creating an instance... I dont understand...

Comment: @vmw8 Did you look at what the definition of `clone` is?