# How to create a correct instance in Java?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, instance

I am learning Java and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877014/how-do-i-fix-cannot-resolve-method)
article on stackoverflow.

So there are two classes:

```
public class Image {

...

    public Image clone() {
        Image clone = new Image(getMagicNumber(), getHeight(), getWidth(), getMax());
        for (int i = 0; i < getHeight(); i++){

            for (int j = 0; j < getWidth(); j++){
                clone.setPixel(getPixel(i, j), i, j);
             }
        }
        return clone;
    }
}
```

And than there is this class:

```
public class Filter {

    public Filter() {

    }

    public Image linearFilter(Image image, float[][] kernel) {
        Image filtered = image.clone();

        ...

         return filtered;
    }
}
```

I am used to do `X instancename = new X();` for creating an instance, where `X` is the name of the class. Are there different ways for creating an instance? For example in the `Filter` class: How is `Image filtered = image.clone();` creating an instance? In order to create an instance I thought on both sides of the "equation" X has to be equal. What I mean by this: `Image filtered = new Image();`. I don't understand how `Image filtered = image.clone();` is creating a new instance. Can someone explain?

Comment: within the clone method, don't you see the = new ... ? it's exactly the same

Comment: If you would have the source code for `Image`, you would see that `Image#clone` or one of its called methods would be the one to call `new Image(...)`. Cloning an image simply hides the logic needed to create a new image while preserving the clone-semantics.

Comment: Wherever you learned both sides need to be "equal" is wrong. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459553/why-do-some-people-use-the-list-base-class-to-instantiate-a-new-arraylist More correctly, both sides must be related, with the left side being a higher order object

Comment: Does that mean if you have the classes A and B and within A there is a method called `clone` which creates an instance `A name = new A();`  you can just create an instance in B by doing `Type newname = variable.clone()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Image filtered = image.clone();
```

Is same as

```
Image filtered = new Image();
```

you can see thet `clone()` is a method of your class which return the `instance` of the class `Image`

**But making instance using methods like `clone()` are supportive when you want to create only one instance of your class, you can make the instance of your class `public and final`, and return it using a public  method.**

Answer (score 1):

> class: How is Image filtered = image.clone(); creating an instance?

It is creating an instance as you can see that the method `clone()` is returning the type `Image`, the first line of the method is showing this :

`Image clone = new Image(getMagicNumber(), getHeight(), getWidth(), getMax());`

and at last of this method `clone` is returned,this was the logic

I hope it helps

Comment: Does that mean if you have the classes A and B and within A there is a method called clone which creates an instance A name = new A(); you can just create an instance in B by doing Type newname = variable.clone()?

Comment: Yes,but only if that method clone returns an instance of type A

Comment: according to your question in comments,clone() should return name which is an instance of class A

Comment: Lest say we don't have the clone method in the class Image. But I want to do the same. Should I first create an instance in the class Filter by doing "Image filtered = new Image()"? Would this be the same?

Comment: Yeah it will be same,because at last you are returning the instance of class Image in both the cases